# Output array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I `console.log(arrayname)` I get this:

[image]

How do I Output the value `"test"`?

Comment: What? This is unreadable. I suggest you clean up the question.

Comment: Using `arrayname[0]`. I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: The edit makes the question even more unclear.

Comment: I've fixed the question for you. Again, though, I strongly recommend deleting it and instead working through some tutorials.

Comment: using arrayname[0] don't print "test".

Answer (score 1):

Just take the index of the array.

```js
var arrayname = ['test'];
console.log(arrayname[0]);
//                   ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var foo = Array('bar', 'baz', 'qux');
alert(foo[0]); //First item
alert(foo[1]); //Second item
alert(foo[2]); //Third item
```